# Верно ли словосочетание "Внизу окна"

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, точное-словоупотребление

Верно ли словосочетание "Внизу окна" при описании элемента интерфейса компьютерной программы. Например: "Внизу окна располагается индикатор загрузки программы". Является ли данное словосочетание речевой ошибкой или оно верно и может употребляется в данном контексте?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, данное словосочетание допустимо в том случае, если оно используется в качестве сокращенной формы словосочетания "в самом низу окна", т.е. не просто в его нижней части, а именно **в самом низу**.

Во всех остальных случаях более корректным будет вариант "в нижней части окна".

Приведенный вами пример ***"внизу окна располагается индикатор загрузки программы"*** будет допустим в том случае, если индикатор находится, например, в узкой строке статуса, расположенной в самом низу окна. Если же этот индикатор занимает чуть ли не всю нижнюю половину окна, будет правильнее сказать ***"в нижней части окна располагается индикатор загрузки программы"***.